# application.js can't find the file I'm including

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, bower

I installed textAngular with Bower. But I'm having a hard time getting it to work. Anyone tried to add it with Rails and Bower?

```
$ rake bower:install && find . -name "*textAngular*" -print
./lib/assets/bower_components/textAngular
./lib/assets/bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular-sanitize.min.js
./lib/assets/bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular.min.js
./lib/assets/bower_components/textAngular/src/textAngular-sanitize.js
./lib/assets/bower_components/textAngular/src/textAngular.js
./lib/assets/bower_components/textAngular/src/textAngularSetup.js
```

Adding textAngular to **application.js** works. But adding textAngular-sanitize failes. A bit weird as I can see the source file next to textAngular.

```
// [snipp...]
//= require textAngular           => No complaining here. 
//= require textAngular-sanitize  => couldn't find file 'textAngular-sanitize'
//= require_tree .
```

And added to **app.js**

```
angular
  .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'restangular', 'textAngular'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', 'RestangularProvider', function($routeProvider, RestangularProvider) {
```

Answer (score 2):

The important line is

```
./lib/assets/bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular-sanitize.min.js
```

Your require should look like:

```
//= require textAngular/dist/textAngular-sanitize
```

Comment: Nah, that did not work: `couldn't find file => 'textAngular/dist/textAngular-sanitize'`  `require textAngular` on the line above works without any errors.

Comment: Try `textAngular-sanitize.min`? I missed the min before; if that works I'll update the answer. I'm basing this on similar errors I've gotten before, and seeing that I needed to provide the full path from `bower_components` to the desired file, minus the extension.

Comment: Nope, didn't work that either. I tried adding different extensions to the line above with `textAngular`. It only works if I don't prepend any extension. As `find` shows that there is a `textAngular-santize` file next to the `textAngular` file, I really don't understand why Rails only finds one of the.